# Typescript Decorators state

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

**TypeScript Version:** 1.8

Hello,

We have a good case to use TypeScript Decorators in our project but there are next lines in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html:

> Decorators are a stage 1 proposal for JavaScript and are available as an experimental feature of TypeScript. 
>  NOTE  Decorators are an experimental feature that may change in future releases.

**So we have next questions:**
1) Will decorators' syntax be changed in future? 
2) Could we use decorators for production?

Comment: You quoted yourself that `"Decorators are an experimental feature that may change in future"` so to answer your 1st question: yes, they might. As for question #2: The current implementation works and you can use it, but take into account that later typescript versions might have breaking changes so you'll need to change your code in order to use the newer versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will decorators' syntax be changed in future?

It may. Although it seems its unlikely at this stage due to its prevalence.

> Could we use decorators for production?

I use them from third party libraries all the time (e.g. `@connect` in redux). However I am weary to create them myself (the burden is on the creator)